# How can I automatically increment numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, auto-increment

I am using C# 2008 Windows Forms application.

In my project there is a `TextBox` control and in that I want make an auto generate numbers for samples s00, next when I come back to form again it should be increment like s01,s02,s03......like that

Please help me

Answer (score 7):

Quite easy. Keep a variable to keep the current number.

```
int incNumber = 0;
```

Then on click of button, generate the number string like this:

```
string nyNumber = "s" + incNumber.ToString("00");
incNumber++;
```

Comment: I think you still need to increment the number though. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Do as suggested by *Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen* but if you want it to be done automatically when **form** is **Deactivated** and **Activated** (You come back to the form and give it focus) then you can do somthing like this.

*This only works if you are sure the text in box will always be in the mentioned format*

```
this.Activated += (s, ev)=>{ 
         string tmp = textbox1.Text; 
         int num = String.Substring(1) as int;              
         if(nuum != null) 
         {
             num++;
             textbox1.Text = "s" + num.Tostring();  
         }
      };
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen said: Keep track of the integer using a variable. Only you should format it like this (Microsoft preferred):

```
int incNumber = 0;

string formattedIncNumber = String.Format("s{0:D2}", incNumber);
incNumber++;
```

Or if you want to do it with one line less code:

```
int incNumber = 0;

string formattedIncNumber = String.Format("s{0:D2}", incNumber++);
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString) for a complete reference for formatting integers.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly better variation of oyvind-knobloch-brathen's above:

```
int incNumber=0;
s + String.Format("{0:00}", incNumber);  
incNumber++;
```

//s00, s01, s02. If you want, say, the range 0001-9999, just change "00" to "0000", etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the text component of the string is unknown (with or without a number at the end of the string), variations of this function may be helpful:

```
        private string increment_number_at_end_of_string(string text_with_number_at_the_end)
        {
            string text_without_number = text_with_number_at_the_end.TrimEnd('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
            string just_the_number = text_with_number_at_the_end.Substring(text_without_number.Length);

            int number = -1;
            if (int.TryParse(just_the_number, out number))
            {
                return text_without_number + (number + 1).ToString();
            }
            return text_with_number_at_the_end;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This For auto generation of number and auto incrementation of number:

```
// Stock is table name
// metal id is unique number that is auto generated as well as auto incremented


private void textBox9_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "select max(metalid)+1 from stock";
    SqlCommand csm = new SqlCommand(s, con);

    con.Open();
    csm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlDataReader dd = csm.ExecuteReader();

    while (dd.Read())
    {
        int n = dd.GetInt32(0);
        textBox1.Text = n.ToString();
    }

     con.Close();
}
```

Comment: OP is not dealing with databases.

Answer (score 0):

Another single line approach would be:

```
string sampleNum = "s" + (counter++).ToString("00");
```

Where **counter** defines like this:

```
int counter= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to generator auto incremented id in C# which don't need to increase or do anything. It will just work. whenever a new object created its value will increase by 1.

```
public class Employee
    {
        static long AutoId = 0;
        public long Id { get; private set; } = ++AutoId;
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
{  try {  //madhura//  SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"select 'Column_name'+ REPLACE(STR(MAX(CAST(Right(Column_name,5) as int)+1 ),6),SPACE(1),'0') as Column_name from TabelName ", con);  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);   DataTable dt = new DataTable();  da.Fill(dt);
```

if (dt.Rows[0][" Column_name'"].ToString() == null)  {  Label1.Text = "DMBP-000001";   }  else{ Label.Text= dt.Rows[0][" Column_name'"].ToString();  }  }  catch { }  }

Comment: What does it have to do with the question?