# auto increment numbers in c# windows app

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [auto generating numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897658/auto-generating-numbers)

how to increment a numbers in textbox control in c# windows app.samples like s001 and should be increment always when i come to form it should be like s002.where should i have to write a code either in textbox or forml_load event.

Comment: What does it mean "when I come to form"? Is it applied if you minimize and restore the form?

Comment: **[Not you again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897658/auto-generating-numbers)...** You just asked this question. What was wrong with the answers given there?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code at an appropriate place in your form to increment *TextBox*'s value by one:

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:000}", Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text) + 1);
```

Comment: He can't do that with an s at the beginning of the string though can he?

Comment: Ya, I missed that. I guess you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You must write the code in Form_load event and the number must be publicly define...

each time to load the form the textbox text must be loaded with new value.